# Hash assignment with List::Util

Tags: perl

Here is the small code

```
use List::Util qw(first);

my $x = {FOO => undef};
my @array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

$x->{FOO} =
    {
        'INFO' => first { $_ eq 1 } @array,
        'TI' => first { $_ eq 2 } @array,
    };
```

It's not creating the nested hash - the anonymous hashref FOO has only one keypair. Here is the o/p

```
$VAR1 = {
          'FOO' => {
                     'INFO' => 1
                   }
        };
```

I am unable to figureout why is this happening? please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `first` function has the prototype of `&@`, which means that it takes a block and a list as arguments. Everything after the block is used as the list. Therefore your code is equivalent to:

```
$x->{FOO} = {    
    'INFO' => first { $_ eq 1 } (@array, 'TI' => first { $_ eq 2 } @array),
};
```

You can either put the whole `first` expression in parens, or use an anonymous sub:

```
$x->{FOO} = { 
    'INFO' => first(sub { $_ eq 1 }, @array),
    'TI'   => first(sub { $_ eq 2 }, @array),
};
```

Comment: @rpg: weird. `map` does support that syntax, for example.

Comment: Much more simple to pass an anonymous sub to `first`: `INFO => first(sub{ $_ eq 1 }, @array),` etc.